# mpi wrapper library path order

Tags: linker, mpi

When adding `-L` paths to the `mpicc` wrapper, the path is added at the **beginning** of the list instead of the end. This can lead to prioritize this path with respect to the implicit paths that the wrapper has.

If a different mpi installation is present in that path, the compilation may fail. It happened to me when a library appended `-L/usr/lib` when trying to compile with an mpi installation from a different folder while having a system-wide mpi installation.

Is there a way to circumvent this?

Comment: Never add `-L/usr/lib` in the first place! Open MPI has the option to generate a (hackable) shell script for the wrappers.

Comment: I do agree that `-L/usr/lib` should never be added, but it is inserted by a (custom...) build system of  a library that I am not keen to hack.

Comment: `mpicc --show`, copy that, and use hard-coded absolute paths to the libraries. And then go and insult the author of that build system.